# ASUS RT-AXE7800 router; unable to show ALL connected devices - why?

Tags: networking, wireless-router, dhcp

My network is straight forward. I have an ASUS RT-AXE7800 router which provides DHCP to which is attached my ISP provided router / modem in BRIDGE mode. It's a FTTH connection.
I have multiple power line adapters to which are connected WiFi access points. It all works very well.
I have a main (private) network and a guest network.  (The guest network is within the same IP range of the main network but users are restricted with access only to the internet).
So, the Network Map Client list will show all WiFi and wired clients that are connected TO the router itself. So, that includes PCs, printers using the power line adapters and all devices within the WiFi range of the router itself. However, what is **not included** are any WiFi clients (private or guest network) that are using the WiFi access points. They simply do not exist on the client list.
Please tell me a way that I can see every device that is connected to my network
Thanks

Comment: Are your wi-fi access points *really* just access points, or are they whole routers? Do they run their own DHCP?

Comment: No. They are simply Wi-Fi access points which, via a power line adapter routs to the ASUS router which provides DHCP and then internet access.